# Activeadmin Rails register model multiple times - confuses routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, activeadmin

I'm trying to setup the same model in multiple menus, one as a sortable tree and the other as a regular crud. This instance registered as a crud is nested within another model
so.. I have

```
ActiveAdmin.register Parent do
end

ActiveAdmin.register Child do
  belongs to :parent
end

ActiveAdmin.register Child, as: 'Child1' do
  menu :parent => "Parent1"
end

ActiveAdmin.register Child, as: 'Child2' do
  menu :parent => "Parent1"
end
```

This works on my local machine but goes crazy when deployed to heroku. Activeadmin seems to get confused about which route to use between all the children that are registered.
Has anyone run into this and been able to solve it?

Appreciate any help I can get... Thanks!

Gems:
activeadmin 1.0.0.pre 
rails 4.2

Comment: heroku run rake routes tells me that the routes are not being setup correctly on heroku

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to namespace it.
Whenever registering a model more than once for any reason whatsoever, the routes will get messed up randomly if they are in the same namespace